# How to make smooth line joints in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to make straight line chart but with border-smoothed angles (joints) like in the image below:

[image: Chart line smoothed]

Is it possible at all (interpolation is not working in this way)? JS example which I found is based on vuetrend - https://jsfiddle.net/nyh18bLq/426/

```
Vuetrend init code
```